Microsoft mouse wheel scrolls very very slowly. Cant find a setting in Kubuntu to ajust the speed
System specs:
Operating System: Kubuntu 24.04
KDE Plasma Version: 5.27.11
KDE Frameworks Version: 5.115.0
Qt Version: 5.15.13
Kernel Version: 6.8.0-40-generic (64-bit)
Graphics Platform: X11
Processors: 8 × Intel® Core™ i7-8650U CPU @ 1.90GHz
Memory: 15.5 GiB of RAM
Graphics Processor: Mesa Intel® UHD Graphics 620
Manufacturer: Dell Inc.
Product Name: Latitude 7390
Microsoft 4000 wireless mouse

How would I ajust the scroll speed of my mouse wheel? It is so slow.

Tried Setting, System Setting, under Hardware, Input Devices, Mouse?

Try this answer.

Experienced the same problem in ubuntu 22.04.4 with a Logitech MX Anywhere 3 Mouse. The imwheel made it just more wonky. This change rendered my mouse wheel useless. The lack of accessible settings in ubuntu makes it just worse.

I have the same setup as @user426486. This seems to be a kernel issue, so try booting into an earlier kernel in grub's "advanced options for Ubuntu". For me it works fine on kernel 6.5.0-45-generic, but not 6.8.0-40-generic which came with the latest update.

Thanks for all the suggestion!
